# SQL CLR Calling SqlFunction declared in parent class

Tags: c#, sql, sqlclr

I have several classes to proceed some calculations.
They can be called one at time from SqlServer, or in batch from Web Application.
So I created base class to combine common logic

```cs
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T: BaseClass<T>, new()
{
    [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, FillRowMethodName = "GetRow")]
    public static IEnumerable Calculate(int param1)
    {
        return new T().calc(param1);
    }

    public static void GetRow(Object obj, out int result)
    {
        // put some result
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable calc(int param1);
}

public class Child1 : BaseClass<Child1>
{
    protected override IEnumerable calc(int param1)
    {
        // return some result
    }
}

public class Child2 : BaseClass<Child2> ....
```

But when I try to create function in DB, like this:

```
create function sf_calc(@value int)
returns table 
(score int)
as 
external NAME <assembly_name>.[<namespace>.Child1].Calculate;
go
```

I get error:

```
"Msg 6506, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sf_calc, Line 2
Could not find method 'Calculate' for type 'Child1' in assembly '<assembly_name>'"
```

It seems like they forgot to include System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy while reflecting method by name

Is there any way to workaround?